# Oracle get rows that exactly matches the list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a details table and I want to get the record that exactly matches the list of values in another table.
Here is a scenario:

```
OrderDetailTable
OrderID ItemID
1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
2        1
2        2
2        4
3        1
3        2
3        3
4        1
4        2


OrderedTable
 ItemID
    1
    2
```

Now I want to get the OrderID that has the exact ItemID matches with OrderedTable ItemID. In the above scenario OrderID 1 is valid since ItemID 1,2,3 is exactly matched with OrderedTable ItemID.

I used the join but it did not work. It gave me both OrderID 1,2 . How do I do it any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM OrderDetailTable JOIN OrderedTable USING (ItemID)
GROUP BY OrderID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM OrderedTable)
```

The idea, in a nutshell, is as follows:

- Count how many OrderDetailTable rows match OrderedTable by ItemID,
- and then compare that to the total number of ItemIDs from OrderedTable.

If these two numbers are equal, the given OrderID "contains" all ItemIDs. If the one is smaller than the other, there is at least one ItemID not contained in the given OrderID.

Depending on your primary keys, the `DISTINCT` may not be necessary (though it doesn't hurt).

Comment: I ran the query on your test data and it produced only one row (OrderID=1) as a result. How exactly it "did not work"?

Comment: My sample data was not enough before. Now I edited it where it does not work.

Comment: OK, I still get one row (OrderID=1) with the new test data. How is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetailTable WHERE OrderID NOT IN
  (
  SELECT A.OrderID FROM
    (
    SELECT 
      Y.OrderID
      , OT.ItemID
      , (SELECT Z.ItemID 
         FROM OrderDetailTable Z 
         WHERE Z.ItemID = OT.ItemID AND Z.OrderID = Y.OrderID
        )  I 
    FROM OrderDetailTable Y, OrderedTable OT
  ) A 
WHERE A.I IS NULL);
```

**EDIT - as per request the better syntax:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
OrderDetailTable Z WHERE Z.ORDERID NOT IN 
(
SELECT O1 FROM 
(SELECT Y.ORDERID O1, YY.ORDERID O2 FROM 
 OrderDetailTable Y CROSS JOIN OrderedTable OT 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderDetailTable YY ON 
 YY.ORDERID = Y.ORDERID AND YY.ITEMID = OT.ITEMID ) ZZ WHERE ZZ.O2 IS NULL);
```

Comment: +1 Nice query, but why use that awful implicit SQL '89 join (-1) ?

Comment: is there any simple query than this. It works fine but it is little hard to understand what is happenning.

Comment: Thank You Yahia, its easy to understand and it works. But is there any way of doing it without CROSS JOIN, I am thinking about performance. Table that has many records than in the above scenario.

Comment: not that I know of... your requirement is that ItemID from OrderDetail must be checked against ALL values in OrderedTable so that means there either must be a CROSS JOIN or (with the same performance issue) a FOR LOOP which would mean PL/SQL (either Stored Function or anyonymous block)