# Yii/SQL: Get rows that exactly match a list of values

Tags: php, sql, yii

I'm trying to figure out the SQL query for the following case:

I have 2 tables one contains items and another contains properties for each particular item. How could I find all items that match exactly all the properties listed in certain `listOfProperties`? E.g. if `listOfProperties = ['p3','p5','p2']` then item with id=4, which is one of the records returned as result of the query, must contain in table `Properties` 3 records exactly, one for 'p3', 'p5' and 'p2'. As ones can guess table 'Items' and 'Properties' are related in One-to-many type.

Many thanks to all!

P.S. It would be great if you can write the CDbCriteria (in Yii framework) for this query.

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Comment: $JamesBlond The one that @nauphal suggest below but it doesn't satisfy completely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, which is inspired by @nauphal and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154611/oracle-get-rows-that-exactly-matches-the-list-of-values) post:

```
$list = array('p3','p5','p2');
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->alias = 'i';
$criteria->join = ' JOIN item_properties ip ON i.id = ip.item_id';
$criteria->addInCondition('item_property',$list);
$criteria->having = "COUNT(DISTINCT(item_property)) = ".count($list);
$criteria->group = 'i.id';
$items = Items::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->alias = 'i';
$criteria->join = ' JOIN item_properties ip ON i.id = ip.item_id';
$criteria->addInCondition('item_property',array('p3','p5','p2'));
$items = Items::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: $nauphal this will returns also item which have let's say properties 'p3','p5','p2' and 'p10' together or 'p3' and 'p5'.

Comment: let's say we have 3 items: item1 with [p3,p5,p2]; item2 with [p3,p5,p2,p10]; item3 with [p3,p5]. Your query, @nauphal, will return all these items. I want only item1 wich exactly match [p3,p5,p2]. I need exact match of the input list of properties.