# SQL Oracle get rows which matche exactly the list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and I need to get rows which matche a list of values. I've created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/280d0/15) where you can see the result.

This query is used to populate a DropDownList which uses or not autocompletion.
So there are two possible uses for this request: the first is with an empty LIKE ('%') and the second with a populated LIKE ('***%'). Only the first use is problematic because all rows are selected without LIKE condition and I only need those which matches the list of values of PGM column.

My issue is that I can't get the rows which PGM = 'N' and 'L' (according to Fiddle example), not just 'L' or just 'N', nor 'L' and 'N' and 'P': only the pair 'N' and 'L' if this is the values in the list.

```
SELECT al.* FROM ALPHA al WHERE al.PN IN (
    SELECT al2.PN FROM ALPHA al2 WHERE TRIM(al2.PGM) IN ('N','L') AND TRIM(al2.NUM) IN ('2350') AND TRIM(al2.TEAM) = 'R2D2' 
    AND TRIM(al2.PN) LIKE '%' AND (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALPHA al3 WHERE TRIM(al3.PGM) IN ('N','L') AND TRIM(al3.PN) LIKE '%') = 2
)
AND TRIM(al.PGM) IN ('N','L') ORDER BY al.PN ASC;

/*
The idea, in a nutshell, is as follows:
line 1 - Get all rows from ALPHA
line 2 - Get filtered rows from ALPHA according to PGM, NUM, TEAM
line 3 - Filter PN with LIKE (according to autocompletion or not)
line 4 - Get rows which have a PGM = N and PGM = L ONLY | As there are two values in the list it should returns 2 but it does not because of empty LIKE
line 6 - Filter all rows according to PGM
*/
```

I'm aware of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154611/oracle-get-rows-that-exactly-matches-the-list-of-values) but I cannot use it in my case, in PROD I'm working on VIEW not joined TABLES.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to only get the rows where there is an `N` and an `L` for each `PN` that also matches the filters; in that case, use the analytic `COUNT` function with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT sms, pgm, pn, team, num
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(CASE PGM WHEN 'N' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_n,
         COUNT(CASE PGM WHEN 'L' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_l,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN PGM IN ('L', 'N') THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_other
  FROM   ALPHA a
  WHERE  PN   LIKE 'BB%'
  AND    NUM  = '2350'
  AND    TEAM = 'R2D2'
)
WHERE cnt_l > 0
AND   cnt_n > 0
AND   cnt_other = 0
ORDER BY PN ASC;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/280d0/30)

---

If you have a dynamic list then you can create a collection data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE char_list IS TABLE OF CHAR(1);
```

and then use the query:

```sql
SELECT sms, pgm, pn, team, num
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE WHEN PGM MEMBER OF char_list('N', 'L') THEN PGM END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_match,
         COUNT(
           CASE WHEN PGM NOT MEMBER OF char_list('N', 'L') THEN 1 END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_other
  FROM   ALPHA a
  WHERE  PN   LIKE 'BB%'
  AND    NUM  = '2350'
  AND    TEAM = 'R2D2'
)
WHERE cnt_match = CARDINALITY( char_list('N', 'L') )
AND   cnt_other = 0
ORDER BY PN ASC;
```

and, if the client you are using supports it (Java does), you can pass an array as a bind variable to the collection:

```sql
SELECT sms, pgm, pn, team, num
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE WHEN PGM MEMBER OF :your_list THEN PGM END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_match,
         COUNT(
           CASE WHEN PGM NOT MEMBER OF :your_list THEN 1 END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_other
  FROM   ALPHA a
  WHERE  PN   LIKE 'BB%'
  AND    NUM  = '2350'
  AND    TEAM = 'R2D2'
)
WHERE cnt_match = CARDINALITY( :your_list )
AND   cnt_other = 0
ORDER BY PN ASC;
```

If you do not want to use collections then:

```sql
WITH match_values (value) AS (
  SELECT 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT sms, pgm, pn, team, num
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE WHEN PGM IN (SELECT value FROM match_values) THEN PGM END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_match,
         COUNT(
           CASE WHEN PGM NOT IN (SELECT value FROM match_values) THEN 1 END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY PN) AS cnt_other
  FROM   ALPHA a
  WHERE  PN   LIKE 'BB%'
  AND    NUM  = '2350'
  AND    TEAM = 'R2D2'
)
WHERE cnt_match = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match_values)
AND   cnt_other = 0
ORDER BY PN ASC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XmTu9J9K)

Comment: Thank for you answer and fiddle, but in the second query's results there is a row with PN = 'EEEEE'. It should not appear in result because its PGM = N, L and P. I only need rows where PGM matches only N and L. It has to have only those two values not just one among the list's values.

Comment: @Majestic The requirement from your question was not clear and it would have matched two distinct items as I was using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`. I have updated it to count `n` and `l` and other items separately.

Comment: you're right. Thanks for the update it's working ! But I'm afraid I can't use it because I need it to be dynamic on PGM (it could be R, S, T...). Seemed obvious to me because I was working on it but it wasn't for the readers... I'll see if I can use it and build dynamically from backend.

Comment: @Majestic added an update for more dynamic input lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CTE (pgm_filter) and use it later within your WHERE clause.

```sql
WITH
    pgm_filter AS
        (
            Select   PN, PGM_LIST
            From     (SELECT DISTINCT PN, PGM, LISTAGG(PGM, '') WITHIN GROUP (Order By PGM) OVER(PARTITION BY PN) "PGM_LIST"
                      FROM   ALPHA a)
            Where    PGM_LIST  = 'LN'
            Group By PN, PGM_LIST      
        )
```

LISTAGG() analytic function is used to generate a list of PGM values per PN. Where condition filters just the PNs that have your specific combination of values 'L' and 'N' - nothing less and nothing more.
Main SQL with pgm_filter in WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT    SMS, PGM, PN, TEAM, NUM
FROM      ALPHA
WHERE     PN IN(Select PN From pgm_filter) And
          PN   LIKE 'PP%' And
          NUM  = '2350' And
          TEAM = 'R2D2'
```

... this will filter the rows having 'LN' combination of PGM values along with any other filter you need.
Regards...

Comment: @Majestic - You are wellcome. Glad it is usefull. Regards...

Comment: @d r I'd like to validate your post, sorry. But @MT0 's query is more efficient in terms of execution time. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Majestic - Nothing to be sorry about. Better code is better code. We are here to help not to compete.